# How to get azure blob storage data into react app that is hosted on azure app service

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-appservice

Hi I am working on react project ,I want to download huge files ( more than 2.5gb) from azure blob storage to react application , ( scenario is when user click on export button I have text files in azure blob storage I want them to be downloaded to local system ) , I have been looking at few approaches, since I am new to azure I am bit confused

using azure AD we can get access to azure blob storage but since my application is hosted on app service how we can connect these two together or we can have direct access to files through azure app services ?

approach I am currently looking at : [here](https://dev.to/425show/connecting-to-azure-blob-storage-from-react-using-azure-identity-16l0)

Comment: if you follow all the steps of the article that you shared, what is your current issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the resources are from azure, then we should use manage identity or service principle (which also use manage identity under the hood) link in your case.

In your case, you have two azure resources

1. Azure blob storage
2. App Service (which hosted as reactjs application)
   So Here is there is step by step explanation to how you connect and read blob

**In AppService(which hosted as reactjs application)**

1. Go to your Appservice
2. Then Click on `Identity in Left panel`
3. Then On `System assigned` managed identity
4. After `clicking save` button then it generate `Object Id`.
   [image]

In Azure Blob Storage

1. Go to `Your blob storage account`
2. Clicked `Access Control`(IAM)
3. Click `Role Assignment` (RBAC)
4. Click `Add > Add Role assignment`
   [image]
5. Select `Role` as per your need like `Storage Blob Data Reader`
6. Click `Next` > `Select Managed Identity` > `Select Member`
7. Then `Select your Subscription` then `App Service`
8. Then `List of Managed identity` are shown > `Select your App Service` one which need to connect with storage
9. Then click on `Select` and then `Next`
   [image]
10. Then You get the below screen. Match `object id` which generated in `step 4` to below grid
    [image]
11. Then Click `Next` > `Next` > `Review + assign`

Now **In React Js Application**

12. We can add these `two Dependencies` in package.json and do an npm i to install.
    [image]
13. Now `connect blob storage with DefaultAzureCredential` from @azure/identity package :- when we give permission /access of one azure to another azure resource directly using service principle or managed identity then we use default azure credential then azure automatically validate them.
    Code
    `For Import package`

```
                import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";
               // we're using these objects from the storage sdk - there are others for different needs
               import { BlobServiceClient, BlobItem } from "@azure/storage-blob";
```

14. `Create service client and container`

```
               const blobStorageClient = new BlobServiceClient(
                // this is the blob endpoint of your storage acccount. Available from the portal 
               // they follow this format: <accountname>.blob.core.windows.net for Azure global
               // the endpoints may be slightly different from national clouds like US Gov or Azure China
                 "https://<your storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
                   new DefaultAzureCredential()
                 )

             // this uses our container we created earlier
        var containerClient = blobStorageClient.getContainerClient("your container name");
```

15. Get list of blob

```
        let blobs = containerClient.listBlobsFlat();
        for await (const blob of blobs) {
         console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
  }
```

16. Download blob

```
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

  // Get blob content from position 0 to the end
  // In Node.js, get downloaded data by accessing downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody
  const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();
  const downloaded = (
    await streamToBuffer(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)
  ).toString();
  console.log("Downloaded blob content:", downloaded);

  // [Node.js only] A helper method used to read a Node.js readable stream into a Buffer
  async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const chunks = [];
      readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
        chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
      });
      readableStream.on("end", () => {
        resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
      });
      readableStream.on("error", reject);
    });
  }
```

For More Details, Go through the below links

1. [Azure Storage Blob client library for JavaScript - version 12.12.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-node-latest)
2. [Quickstart: Manage blobs with JavaScript SDK in Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli)

Comment: This is a bit strange. For step 14, I am getting `Error: DefaultAzureCredential is not supported in the browser. Use InteractiveBrowserCredential instead.` I am getting this with `@azure/storage-blob": "^12.12.0` and `@azure/identity": "^3.1.2`

Comment: where are you getting this. on local system or qa/prod( where your app service is host).You cannot use this on your local system.

Comment: The DefaultAzureCredential is appropriate for most scenarios where the application is intended to ultimately be run in Azure.

Comment: Please let me know so that i can help you properly

Comment: Ah, yes I am trying to run this locally (localhost:3000). So I guess, this is the reason why it is not working...

Comment: for local you can use SAS Token/Connection string of blob storage or if you have any user on Azure where is blob storage then you can give RBAC to that user and login to azure by that user in your IDE Like visual code or visual studio through AZ login command then you can use default credential

Comment: [go through this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-node-latest) i hope my comments help you